# Controlling input values in React (.ts file)

Tags: reactjs

In the below code, I want to trigger the message 'Invalid verification code.' when the value input is more than 6 digits. It will work for inputs that are less than 6 digits.

```
export const verifyValidation: IVerifyValidation = {
  code: {
    code: {
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: 'Invalid verification code.',
      },
      pattern: {
        value: /[0-9]{6}/,
        message: 'Invalid verification code.',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regex, change {6} to {1,6}

Comment: Thanks. However, {1,6} doesn't trigger any message anymore. I need to have trigger a message for all values that are not 6 digits.

Comment: In your post, you mentioned « It will work for inputs that are less than 6 digits. » which lead me to think you want to accept any number that is equal or less than 6 digits. Could you clarify what you are your current problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

I've added the following ***maxLength*** condition to make it work.

```
export const verifyValidation: IVerifyValidation = {
  code: {
    code: {
      required: {
        value: true,
        message: 'Invalid verification code.',
      },
    maxLength: {
        value: 6, 
        message: 'Invalid verification code.'
      },
    pattern: {
        value: /[0-9]{6}/,
        message: 'Invalid verification code.',
      },
    },
  },
};
```